Running firebase CLI commands on Vercel throws: "firebase: command not found" error
We are currently hosting our application on Vercel and encountering an issue when attempting to execute Firebase CLI commands.
When trying to deploy Firestore rules using Firebase CLI within our Vercel environment, we receive the error message: still stderr: /bin/sh: firebase: command not found. We managed to use the correct PATHs and ENVs:
const firebaseDeploy = spawn(`firebase`, ['deploy', '--only', `firestore`], {
    env: firebaseEnv,
    shell: true,
    cwd: process.cwd()
});

Is it an import issue or something else?
Maybe that simply cannot be done inside a Vercel deployment, who knows? Unfortunately the documentation is really poor and just redirects you to the Vercel CLI project when looking up any keyword regarding this bug.
Tried switching the imports, paths, env, npm installations and version. No documentation can be found.

Seems to me that you'd have to install the CLI in that environment before trying to execute it.  Did you do that?  If so, could you edit the question to show everything you've done so we can duplicate that and see what you might be doing wrong?

What do you exactly mean by installing in the environment? The package is installed as the other ones (npm install) and can be found in the package.json as a devDependecy: firebase-tools": "^13.5.2. Is there any other correct way to do this in Vercel? Thank you so much for your help btw.
